# Instantiate overloaded function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I encountered this problem when using `std::cref`. A minimal example looks like this:

```
template<typename Fn, typename T>
auto apply(Fn f, const T &t) -> decltype(f(t))
{
    return f(t);
}

int n = 123;
apply(std::cref<int>, n);  // <- compile error: can't infer type `Fn`
apply([](const int &x) { return std::cref(x); }, n);  // ok
```

I think the problem with the first example is that `std::cref<T>` has two overloaded versions, one accepting a `const T &` and the other accepting a `std::reference_wrapper<const T>`. Is it possible to instantiate a specific version in my case?

Comment: `apply(static_cast<std::reference_wrapper<const int>(*)(const int&)>(&std::cref<int>), n);`, but what's wrong with the lambda ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I was trying to do something like `fmap(std::cref, foos)` to transform a `std::vector<Foo>` to a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const Foo>>`, and without the lambda the syntax would look cleaner. But that's probably not possible!

Comment: you could add your own reference-wrapping function and have `fmap(mycref, foos)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe problem is that  [`cref`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/cref/?kw=cref)  has several forms.  So when you write `cref<int>` it is not yet clear which of the following you mean:

```
reference_wrapper<const int> cref (const int& elem)
reference_wrapper<const int> cref (reference_wrapper<int>& x)
```

The lambda version doesn't have this ambiguity. By the way, it's a good idea to get accustomed to it ;-)

Now if the readability is really an issue, nothing prevents you from doing this:

```
auto take_ref = [](const int &x) { return std::cref(x); }; 
apply(take_ref, n);  // compile fine
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `apply` function seems kind of redundant in this case. Why not cut the middleman?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> v2;
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v2),
        static_cast<std::reference_wrapper<const int>(*)(const int&)>(&std::cref<int>));
}
```

Comment: The `apply` function is contrived to simplify the real code. In the real situation it's actually something similar to `std::transform`.